# How to create tree via Github API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, github-api

I am trying programmatically create a git commit and as part of that I need to create a [git tree](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree).

Having read the docs, I am unsure what to send in the request body.

I am able to create a blob and get a sha response but when I try call the create tree endpoint, I get the following:

```
{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/git/trees/",
    "status": 404,
    "statusText": "Not Found",
    "body": {
        "message": "Not Found",
        "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
    }
}
```

My code looks like this where I create the blob and then try create the tree:

```
const blobContent = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../../templates/main.yaml', { encoding: "utf8" })

const blob = await this.post<IBlobResponse>(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/blobs`, {
  content: blobContent,
  encoding: "utf-8"
})

const tree = await this.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees/`, {
  base_tree: masterRef.object.sha,
  tree: [
    {
      path: "main.yaml",
      mode: "100644",
      type: "tree",
      sha: blob.sha,
      content: blobContent
    }
  ]
})
```

Is the payload for creating the tree correct?

1. Should `path` be the local relative path or is it the path that the file will live in inside the repository?
2. Do I need both the `sha` and the `content`?
3. Is the fact that the content is a yaml file an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was including a trailing `/` in the POST endpoint when creating a tree:

Changed `https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees/` to `https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees` and it worked.

Very simple fix but thought I'd share incase anybody else has a similar issue

Comment: Just spent half an hour with this silly issue. THANK YOU.